# Data Validation & Sanitization for Big HTML Blocks

Tags: theme-development, validation, sanitization

I'm developing a theme for Envato. Got Soft Reject because of issue typed in the question title. I created a 4 column widget area for my theme's footer. How can I sanitize the $output variable?

[image: Code Block]

Thank you all.

Comment: And why do you use any buffering in there?

Comment: The main problem is sanitization it's not buffering. But is there another proper way to do the same? I'm calling in at footer.php.

Comment: the main problem with such automatic tests is that they don’t understand the code. So in this case the problem is that your function returns HTML and you don’t sanitize anything. But on the other hand there is not much to sanitize... So there is a chance that it is a false positive caused by very original (not exactly in a good way) way of processing sidebars.

Comment: I fixed other sanitization & validation errors. Only this thing left. Will the reviewer ignore this sanitization warning? Thank your for attention.